# error: no suitable constructor found for PriorityQueue(Comparator)

Tags: java, priority-queue

I was trying to initialize the priority queue but I found this error:

```
import java.util.*;
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

error: no suitable constructor found for PriorityQueue(Comparator)

I tried to find the solution but no solution till now.
Any suggestion would be better.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: weird it compiles on my side

Comment: Please refer to the Java doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html. That should give you an idea about all the constructors for this class

Comment: Which version of Java do you have? This constructor is only available from Java 8. Maybe you mix Java 7 and Java 8

Comment: Java 7 has no constructor for `PriorityQueue` that takes only a `Comparator` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), Java 8 has one (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). So it depends on which java version you use.

Comment: This compiles good.. no errors.. check your java version

Answer (score 4):

The constructor that takes a `Comparator` also requires an initial capacity.

For example `new PriorityQueue<Integer>(100, Collections.reverseOrder());`.

(Or upgrade your Java)

Comment: Not from Java 8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: But that doesn't help him since he's not on Java 8.

Comment: It could be that they _want_ to be on Java 8... in which case it is another issue.